# Is it possible to update data contained in a 'Chart In Microsoft PowerPoint' from data entered in a PowerPoint UserForm

Tags: excel, powerpoint, userform, vba

A chart was created through the *Chart In Microsoft PowerPoint* feature and we would like to control how the chart is updated by using a PowerPoint Userform.  Is there a line of code that can point to sheet named `DVPVreport` located within the *Chart In Microsoft PowerPoint* when the routine is executed?  Current code is below which does not consider that the `DVPVreport` is located within the Chart In Microsoft PowerPoint.  We tried to execute code:

```
Set ws = 'Chart In MicrosoftPowerPoint!'.Worksheets(DVPVreport)
```

but without success.

```
Private Sub AddDVSetUp_Click()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("DVPVreport")

   ws.Cells(3, 4).Value = Gate2Date.Value
   Unload M

   ws.Cells(3, 5).Value = Gate3Date.Value
   Unload M

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Try this:

```
Dim sl As Slide
Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Dim xlWB As Object
Dim sh As Shape, ch As Chart

For Each sh In sl.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoChart Then
        Set ch = sh.Chart
        Set xlWB = ch.ChartData.Workbook
        With xlWB.Sheets(1) '/* It has only 1 sheet so this will be fine */
            '/* Do the changes you want here */
            .Range("B2").Value = 4.2
        End With
    End If
Next
Set ch = Nothing: Set xlWB = Nothing: Set sl = Nothing '/* clean up */
```

Now, if you already know the index or name of your object, you can simply:

```
Dim sl As Slide
Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Dim xlWB As Object
Dim sh As Shape

Set sh = sl.Shapes("Chart 1")
Set xlWB = sh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook

With xlWB.Sheets(1)
    .Range("B2").Value = 4.2
End With
```

**Important:** Be very careful not to ruin the source data layout. It de-associates the chart with the `ChartData` for some reason when you do this.

Comment: Works great L42.  To improve the flexibility of this slide within a presentation,  is there a work around for the (1) in connection with ActivePresentation.Slide(1)?  There will be times when this slide is not the first slide in the presentation.  It could be anywhere from slide 8 to 15.

Comment: @M.Boes I leave that part to you :). If you know the specific name of the Chart Object then you can simple loop trough all slides and check where the chart reside. I used `ActivePresentation.Slides(1)` for demonstration purpose.